# illegall string offset warning while fetching db data

Tags: php, mysql

What is wrong here:

```
$items = '';
$st = $db->query("select code from map where pos = 'home01' limit 1");
$res = $st->fetchColumn();  // result: 1-2-3-4
$arr = explode("-", $res);
foreach($arr as $el) {
    $st = $db->query("select fname from banners where fname = " . $el . " limit 1");
    $row = $st->fetchColumn();
    $items .= "<img class='imgr imgr2' data-fname = '" . $row['fname'] . "' src='../banners/" . $row['fname'] . ".jpg' alt='img'>\n"; // line 88
}
echo $items;
```

**Warning:**
`Illegal string offset 'fname' ... on line 88`

Comment: `$row = $st->fetchColumn();` I expect it should return `array("a", "b", "c")` not `array('fname' => "a")`;

Comment: `var_dump($row)` Like @degr said, `$row['fname']` does not exist !

Comment: Instead of `$row['fname']` just use `$row` because `fetchColumn` doesn't return array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fetchColumn`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) returns the next column directly, not an array that represents the row:

```
$fname = $st->fetchColumn();
$items .= "<img class='imgr imgr2' data-fname = '${fname}' src='../banners/${fname}.jpg' alt='img'>\n";
```

Comment: not sure that you are right, because fetchColumn should return column, not cell. If you have `limit 1` it should return array with one element, so, proper way to use it will be `reset($fname)` or `$fname[0]`

Comment: @degr this is the right way to use `fetchColumn` - check out the examples in the documentation page I linked to.